# Error connecting meteor to external mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongohq

I have a meteor web app that connects to a mongohq database. It's working correctly on heroku, but I can't get it to work on my localhost. It was working on localhost yesterday, but not today.

To be certain, I just ran a git clone in a new folder. Even this clone is throwing errors on localhost. Here's my terminal (FYI, I'm on a windows 8.1 machine that is running an Ubuntu virtual box; also, I've removed the username / password from the log, below):

```
adam@adam-VirtualBox:~/resSingleTestV2/faze1tables$ export MONGO_URL=mongodb://<username>:<password>@oceanic.mongohq.com:10033/test_db
adam@adam-VirtualBox:~/resSingleTestV2/faze1tables$ meteor
[[[[[ ~/resSingleTestV2/faze1tables ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started your app.   

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
I20140511-12:53:43.438(-4)? Exception in callback of async function: Error: failed to connect to [oceanic.mongohq.com:10033]
I20140511-12:53:43.637(-4)?     at null.<anonymous> (/home/adam/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/0120179b5c/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:536:74)
I20140511-12:53:43.640(-4)?     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
I20140511-12:53:43.641(-4)?     at null.<anonymous> (/home/adam/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/0120179b5c/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:150:15)
I20140511-12:53:43.641(-4)?     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
I20140511-12:53:43.643(-4)?     at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/adam/.meteor/packages/mongo-livedata/0120179b5c/npm/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:516:10)
I20140511-12:53:43.643(-4)?     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
I20140511-12:53:43.644(-4)?     at net.js:440:14
I20140511-12:53:43.644(-4)?     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: just uninstalled and re-installed meteor. Problem still exists.

Comment: I just tested connecting to a local mongodb, and everything works. Strange that my Heroku app is running and connecting to mongoHQ, but I can't locally.

Comment: Maybe try surrounding the url with quotes: `MONGO_URL="..." meteor`

Comment: @DavidWeldon Thanks for the suggestion, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Try creating a new user for the local connection.

Comment: Also, double check that you're using the actual **password** in your `MONGO_URL`, not the **password hash** displayed in the MongoHQ dashboard. That's what I did once.

Comment: @HubertOG thanks for both suggestions. I created a new user with a real simple username / password and still no luck. I've got a ticket on MongoHQ. Hopefully they can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm connecting via my school's wifi. Turns out they must've done something to prevent me from connecting to mongoHQ because I'm able to connect via other networks.

Strange that it worked for a day or two and then stopped.